# How to cite a result from a particular paper in a desired manner?

Tags: citing, theorems

I want to mention a theorem from a paper. I am using the \cite reference style.
I used the following code(**WinEdt Latex**):

```
We have following lemma $\cite{singh1}$ to find $**************************$.
```

And it is showing in following manner:

[image].

I want the Lemma to start as:

> **Lemma 1.2** *[XYZ, 17]*

How to write in this format?

**My tex code and output:**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{latexsym} 
\usepackage{amsthm,amsmath,amssymb,amsmath,amsfonts,graphicx,fancyhdr,algorithmic,longtable,listings,color,epsfig}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage[labelsep=period]{caption}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1in, left=1in, right=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[noadjust]{cite}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{graphicx,subfigure}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat*{\section}{\large\bfseries}% change font of section headings
\usepackage{lipsum} % for filler text
\def\demo{%
  \par\topsep6pt plus6pt
  \trivlist
  \item[\hskip\labelsep\it Proof.]\ignorespaces}
\def\enddemo{\qed \endtrivlist}
\expandafter\let\csname enddemo*\endcsname=\enddemo
\newcommand{\tab}{\hspace*{2em}}
\newtheorem{Theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{Definition}{Definition}[section]
\newtheorem{Proposition}{Proposition}[section]
\newtheorem{Lemma}{Lemma}[section]
\newtheorem{Corollary}{Corollary}[section]
\newtheorem{Example}{Example}[section]
\newtheorem{Remark}{Remark}[section]
\newtheorem{Note}{Note}[section]
\newcommand{\R} {\mbox {$ I\!\!R $}}
\newcommand{\bea}{\begin{eqnarray}}
\newcommand{\eea}{\end{eqnarray}}
\newcommand{\be}{\begin{equation}}
\newcommand{\ee}{\end{equation}}
\newcommand{\nn}{\nonumber}
\newcommand{\nii}{\noindent}
\newcommand{\bee}{\begin{eqnarray*}}
\newcommand{\eee}{\end{eqnarray*}}
\usepackage[us,12hr]{datetime}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{\fancyhf{}
\lfoot{\footnotesize Date :  {\ddmmyyyydate\today}}
\rfoot{ \footnotesize \thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}}
\pagestyle{plain}
\normalsize
\begin{document}
\title{Title of The Paper}
\date{}
\maketitle\begin{abstract}\noindent
The content of the abstract.
\end{abstract}
$~~${\bf Keywords}: 
\section{Introduction}
\noindent Also, we have following lemma \cite{singh1} to .............
\begin{Lemma} \label{distconormal} \cite{singh1} Lemma Statement
\end{Lemma}
\begin{thebibliography}{85}
\bibitem{singh1} P. Singh , Article Title, Journal name.
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This will depend on the way you produce your lemmas (`amsthm`, `theorem`, `thmtools ` ...) and citations (`cite`, `natbib`, `biblatex`, ...). Please show us an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)/[MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864).

Comment: BTW: I don't see any reason to use `\cite` in math mode in your example `We have following lemma \cite{singh1} to` works just as well.

Comment: You can mark up your code by indenting it by four spaces or by clicking the `{}` button. Please do not mark it as a quote, that makes it much harder to read (and quite hard to salvage in an edit). Since your MWE shows that you do not use `biblatex` I have removed that tag.

Comment: @moewe This is the new thing that I learned today. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You should throw out stuff from your preamble that you don't use. Do you really need all packages you load (`epsfig`, `setspace`?; `amssymb` loads `amsfonts`; `mathtools` loads `amsmath`). Macros for `\begin{...}`/`\end{....}` like `\bea`, `\eea` and friends are also not recommended and [`eqnarray` should be avoided](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/196/35864). `\newcommand{\R} {\mbox {$ I\!\!R $}}` looks quite hacky to me, I normally use `\mathbb{R}`, but that's probably a matter of taste.

Comment: Also: don't load packages twice. `subfigure` is obsolete and shouldn't be used. You can't possibly want `lipsum` in your real document and don't use it in your example. You almost certainly don't want `filecontents` either. `epsfig` is also unneeded, though I forget whether it is obsolete, deprecated or something else. Why do you have `\normalsize` in the preamble? `\cite{}` is going to produce the entry label from the bibliography entry. Since you are using `thebibliography`, the facilities you have are pretty basic, but doesn't `\cite[17]{singh1}` give the result you want?